# How can I do a single copy to clipboard even if I press the button multiple times?

Tags: python, tkinter

The append function in the button keeps appending when I press the button multiple times.
There has to be a way to get only one value when clipboard_append()

Basically I need multiple buttons like this so that I don't have to repeatedly copy the text from a google sheet or so, and just paste it in another program. Instead I'll just define certain buttons and just use those to copy texts.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import paperclip



def Click():
    name = button1_Name

    button1.clipboard_append(name)
    button1.update()



window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('300x300')
window.attributes('-topmost', True)

#naming
Prefix = ['ST', 'WS', 'PRP']
Middle = ['Pod', 'Pouffe', 'Sofa']

button1_Name = Prefix[0] + '_' + Middle[0]
button1 = ttk.Button(window, text= button1_Name , command=Click)
button1.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

The code does what its supposed to but it just keeps appending the text multiple times.

Comment: Call `button1.clipboard_clear()` before `button1.clipboard_append(name)`.

Comment: `paperclip` appears to be a Django thing - I think you want `pyperclip`, but I assume that's just a typo